# Default windows wifi password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, passwords

In windows 7, when you go to Control Panel > Hardware And Sound > Add a Device a new wifi "hotspot" (so to speak) is created which can be connected to with an android, ios or other computer. However, a password is needed (I think) in order to connect to the computer and add the device.

If that is so, then is there a default password that is set up for the computer, and if there is, what is that password and how do you change it?

Comment: What is you ultimate goal? Would you like to create a hotpot from your computer for other devices?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be any default password. When you configure hotspot then it will ask you for password. If you are creating virtual wifi hotspot then it will also ask for password.
In settings you can see there are several security option. If you have configured it as open or no password then it will connect directly.